# Day, Time and Date in SQLite in android

Tags: android, datetime

I am doing an app similar to notes. I want to display the Day with Time(Ex:Mon 10:30) for the current week and Date with month and time(5th Sept 11:10) for the previous things. How can I do this?

Comment: What you had tried for this.? *hint : you can compare dates with current date and manipulate format of the date*

Comment: I have just used datetime format so I got 2014-09-05. From this I can get the format which I want

Comment: Ya but I din get the expected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your time in long format in database. While displaying you can use SimpleDateFormat class to display date and time in your required format. e.g.,

```
public static String getReadableDateTime(long timestamp, boolean twentyFourHourFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    if(twentyFourHourFormat)
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    else
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
    Date resultdate = new Date(timestamp);
    return sdf.format(resultdate);
}
```